# Save stream as image

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to save stream as image and store the image in temp files?

Comment: What do you mean by "as an image" exactly?

Comment: Image here means a jpeg image file which is to be stored in temp files location and stream is System.IO.Stream.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try

```
Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myStream);

img.Save(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\myImage.Jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: The image step is not necessary. We can write the stream directly to a file.

Comment: Yes .. But I assumed that banupriyavijay wants to so something with the image in the application. Otherwise it would be just a file copy operation which can be done using System.IO.File.Copy().

Comment: When i write this line Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream); it gives me an error "Parameter is not valid."

Comment: this solution has issues if you are trying to override an image. I am getting a A Generic error occurred in GDI+

Answer (score 7):

```
var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (var fs = File.Create(tempFile))
{
   source.copyTo(fs);
}
```

where source is source stream. Now your source stream is saved at temp location (given by tempFile). Note that file name extension will be TMP.

Comment: +1 for the Path.GetTempFileName() that I didn't know it ever existed.

Comment: FileStream does not contain a definition for Create!! Moreover the stream which i use as input is System.IO.Stream and I want to store this IO stream to image in temp files.

Comment: Sorry for that - I mean to say File.Create and not FileStream.Create. Will edit the answer. Source stream can be of any stream.

Answer (score 3):

Your stream (image) is `stream` in the code below.

```
using (Stream output = new FileStream ("mycat.jpg"))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32*1024];
    int read;

    while ( (read=stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

This code is copyrighted by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) My contribution is the name of the file ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Bitmap Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx). There's a constructor overload that takes a Stream as parameter and there's a method called [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx) which you can use to save it as a file.

Comment: The bitmap step is not necessary. We can write the stream directly to a file.

Answer (score 0):

For windows phone 8.1 I found the following to work well.  Create your TempStorageFile at whatever path you would like and then pass in your image's stream like so:

```
var fileStream = await TempStorageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(imageStream, fileStream);
```