# Upload file to server only with file url

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I need to upload a file to the server.
But I have a folder where my file is located, and this file will be there all the time.

Example: `c:\myfolder\myfile.bmp`

The file will be modified and I have to upload to the server, but without using a control like fileUpload.

I have the publication of file.

How can I upload this file, I´m using ASP.NET aspx

thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: this question can help you out here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083978/fileupload-control-in-visual-studio-and-save-the-image-to-mysql-database

Comment: The client CPUs will always have a directory: k: \\ adn \\ img.bmp
And when doing a process in my web application, I have to load the path of the machine k: \\ adn \\ img.bmp that img.bmp to my server.
But I have to do it in automatic without the user select the file or anything, for that, I already know where the file is located on the client machine.
How can i do that from c #

Comment: I do not know if I explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EveryBody
I resolved my aks with this.

```
eWebClient wc = new WebClient();
            byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData("K://BMP//EKT173026_firmaElectronicaClte.bmp");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
img.Save(strFolder + "\EKT173026_firmaElectronicaClte.bmp");
```

Since my server, I only have the url file and I had to upload the file to the server